# RAML file for OAuth 2.0 spec itsetlf (not an API using OAuth)

Tags: oauth-2.0, raml

Is there a RAML file for the OAuth spec itself?  I am seeing lots of examples of APIs defined in RAML that use OAuth, but I am curious if there is one that would define an OAuth Authorization server itself.